# How to replace emails safety in database dump?

Tags: bash, perl

I have already the command which covers this.

```
perl -pe 's/(([A-z0-9_]|-|\+|\.)+)@([A-z0-9_]|\.|-)+\.[A-z0-9]+/"ss.some.email." . ++$n . "\@example.com"/eg' inputfile.sql > outfile.sql
```

But it can break serialized data - string check length won't match because exist email will be replaced with another random email with different length.

I would like to find some solution which would replace emails with unique or at least random ones but with the same email string length

```
$ cat inputfile.txt
john.doe@gmail.com too.long.email@hotmail.com

$ command_replace inputfile.txt
abc123abc12@aa.com abc123abc123abc123a@aa.com
```

Comment: Why don't you sanitize the data before dumping it? For example, copy the data to a temporary table, hash the email addresses, and then do your dump.

Comment: what is the format of this database dump?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It can be just simple text. The main goal save email length.

Answer (score 1):

If you install [Email::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Find) to your perl, you can do your transformation like this:

```
echo "john.doe@gmail.com too.long.email@hotmail.com" | \
perl -MEmail::Find -pe 'BEGIN{$junk="abc123"x100; $ef=Email::Find->new(sub { substr($junk,0,length $_[0]-7) . "@aa.com"})}; $ef->find(\$_)'
```

Hopefully, none of your emails are more than 607 characters long.  Note that unicode or other non-ascii characters may require a bit more work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yeah, it requires installation of the module. And admin rights on my work laptop.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to share a solution within a team with default environment stuffs. Anyway, this approach should be here as an option. Thanks.

Comment: @Kirby You don't need admin rights to install modules. As for sharing, Email::Find is a pure-Perl module, so the easiest thing is to simply download it and include the source with your script.

Comment: Maybe... What I know I need `cpan` to install a module (http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html). Stuffs in the section Perl on Windows (Win32 and Win64) require admin rights.

Comment: EF also requires some other modules, @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, thus it's a bit more than just copying.

Comment: @Kirby - [Yes, even you can use CPAN](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node=yes%2C+even+you+can+use+cpan)

Comment: @Tanktalus thanks for link. Anyway, for me it's overhead for replacing emails. Base functionality only.

Answer (score -1):

Finally...

Just a bit changed original command... It's a bit complex but it works.

And it's too slow: for database dump 4GB size total time was almost 10 hours.

```
perl -pe 's/(([A-z0-9_]|-|\+|\.)+)@(([A-z0-9_]|\.|-)+\.[A-z0-9]+)/(join("", map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..length($1))) . "@" . (join("", map { (q(a)..q(z))[rand(26)] } 1..length($3)-3)) . ".cc"/eg' path/to/file
```

Result from question will be

```
vxtergkw@juagge.cc viufmhfnwvqubk@vzphosyz.cc
```

I will be really appreciated if someone could optimize the performance of the script.